# preg_match - words with accents

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying this example:

```
$input_line = 'hôhô';
preg_match('/hoho/ui', $input_line, $output_array);
```

But the `output_array` is always empty.

Any solution to working with words with accents?

Comment: If you are looking for a regex that matches accented variations on the word "hoho", this will NOT help you. But if all you need is a regex that matches any sequence of letters, including accented ones, try this: `/^\p{L}+$/ui`

Comment: @KieranPotts so any way to match accented variations in php?

Comment: @stribizhev i want to match a specific word.

Comment: Try this approach in [php preg_grep and umlaut/accent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14073113/3832970) post. You can also leverage this approach here, in [Preg replace with accent letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24651365/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match a specific word, with accented variations, alas you will need to define the alternatives that you will permit for each character. Example:

`/h[oòóôõö]h[oòóôõö]/ui`

Here's a useful reference table for the Unicode character set:

http://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: This works like a sharm! Maybe the best option available.